# unsigned int field in a Ruby on Rails migration?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, migration

How could I make population unsigned?

```
  def self.up
    create_table :cities do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.integer :population
      t.float :latitude
      t.float :longitude

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
```

Comment: FYI, you should now just be able to pass `unsigned: true` to that line and it will make the `integer` unsigned.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This should work for you.

```
t.column :population, 'integer unsigned'
```

Answer (score 7):

Just to add one more thing. This works perfectly. But need to note that it will make the migration code database dependent.

Answer (score 2):

*step 1:*

add activerecord-mysql-unsigned to GemFile

```
# add unsigned integer support to mysql2 adapter
gem "activerecord-mysql-unsigned", "~> 0.0.1"
```

*step 2:*
install gems

```
bundle install
```

*step 3:*

use "unsigned: true" in fields you like

```
t.integer :cost, unsigned: true
```

refrence : http://rubydoc.info/gems/activerecord-mysql-unsigned/0.0.1/frames

Comment: Be VERY careful with this gem if you're working within an existing project. This will _override_ Rails' definition of what a primary_key should be to make it unsigned!

see here -> https://github.com/waka/activerecord-mysql-unsigned/blob/v0.2.0/lib/activerecord-mysql-unsigned/active_record/v3/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb#L7-L9