# Rails 3 migration for adding unsigned int column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-migrations

I would like to generate a migration to add a column to a table which has a data type of unsigned int. I wish to use it to store IP addresses as mentioned here in [this article](https://blogs.law.harvard.edu/zeroday/2009/04/04/storing-ip-addresses-in-mysql-with-rubyrails/).

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156772/unsigned-int-field-in-a-ruby-on-rails-migration) but it will make the migration database dependent, any idea how to do it in a better way?

Comment: I think you should assess mohsen alizadeh's answer below - it is EXACTLY what you want. I cannot confirm database interoperability, however, I was using MySQL, so it was perfect for me. PostgreSQL has it's own :ip_address type support in Rails - so I think that covers all your bases.  He does deserve the "correct answer" tick.

Comment: For the lazy ones that are ok with validations :) `validates :cost, numericality: { greater_than: 0 }`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*step 1:*

add activerecord-mysql-unsigned to GemFile

```
# add unsigned integer support to mysql2 adapter
gem "activerecord-mysql-unsigned", "~> 0.0.1"
```

*step 2:*
install gems

```
bundle install
```

*step 3:*

use "unsigned: true" in fields you like

```
t.integer :cost, unsigned: true
```

refrence : http://rubydoc.info/gems/activerecord-mysql-unsigned/0.0.1/frames

Comment: This is perfect for what I wanted to do, which was to store an IPv4 address as an uni signed int - and not have the PK fields of my database all signed (since an ID would never be negative).

Answer (score 16):

A working solution is shown here that lets you do it slightly more natively inside of a rails migration: [unsigned int field in a Ruby on Rails migration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156772/unsigned-int-field-in-a-ruby-on-rails-migration)

For longevity's sake the answer is to add a custom specification in your options for a typeless column:

```
t.column :population, 'integer unsigned'
```

I believe using 'integer unsigned' is reasonably database independent, but possibly not 100%. You can also use something like 'BIGINT unsigned' if you are willing to lock yourself into a specific database.

Also I'm a bit disappointed in Geoff's answer in that it seems to completely disregard the fact that an unsigned integer while using the same amount of storage space holds a different set of data. If you know you will not be needing negative numbers and are interested in optimizing your data storage needs unsigned ints are valuable. To see the guidelines for mysql, see:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/integer-types.html

It’s important to call out JellicleCat's note below that the schema files will not track this change, so the signed aspect of the column will be lost when the schema is loaded.

Comment: The problem with this answer is that Rails' schema.rb files will never reflect the special 'unsigned' property. So when you set up your application on a new environment and use the schema file to create your database, your application will have a signed field for `population`.

Comment: Great catch, I actually hadn’t noticed that. Assuming that the gem catches that, it would seem to be the better option. Seems odd that Rails let's you pass in the custom config and then loses it. Anyhow a great note, I'll edit the answer to make sure it is prominent.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by execute SQL query,

***in case of MySQL query would be***

**To add new column**

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD column_name INT unsigned;
```

**To delete column**

```
ALTER TABLE table_name DROP column_name;
```

**And migration :**

```
class MyMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    execute "ALTER TABLE table_name ADD column_name INT unsigned;"
  end

  def self.down
     execute "ALTER TABLE table_name DROP column_name;"
  end
end
```

Comment: It will make it database dependent.

Comment: As @shobhit want `unsigned int` which not supported by rails, that why i have suggested execute sql query.

Comment: @user806495 3 times to be precise. Plus, I am teaching Rails to a bunch of people and would like to know it for academic reasons.

Answer (score -7):

Sorry. Unsigned is not one of the supported Rails datatypes.

See section 1.4 of the guide below.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html

I'm not sure why you think you need unsigned. Both integer and unsigned take the same number of bits, being signed just signals a convention that you want to interpret one of the bits as a signed bit. If you assign a value where the signed bit is on, the database will think it's a negative number, but you will know better and you can smile to yourself in the awareness that you are as yet still smarter than the machine.

I hope that helps.

Comment: New versions of MySQL (5.6.x) will fail when you try to put a large IP into a signed int-11 with a message like `Data truncation: Out of range value for column 'ip'`

Comment: Using an unsigned integer in an autoincrement primary key column will give you twice the possible primary keys - e.g. an unsigned int will go to 4 billion versus the signed int 2 billion.

Comment: "... the database will think it's a negative number, but you will know better"

And as long as you are the only person to every deal with that column, life will be good. However, if you work in the real world, then having secrets that only you know is a Bad Thing